# "data-" attributes as part of hyperlinks. HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, window.location, custom-data-attribute

I'm currently developing a Phonegap app and have run into a little trouble with my page transitions.

In order to make my page transitions work, I am using the [FASW.js](http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/) library. I am also using the native navigation bar ([NavigationBar plugin](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NavigationBar)) to provide me with a native back button. I have both working to the point that they respond to user input etc.

To initiate a page transition from the HTML you use:

```
<a href="some_url.html" data-ftrans="slide">Some Link</a>
```

I have that working perfectly.

However in order to make the native back button work, it must be invoked through JavaScript only - like so:

```
function backButton() {

plugins.navigationBar.setupLeftButton("Back", null, function() {
                        //Some function to be called here to change the page 
                        //and to invoke the page transition.
                                      });

[...]

}
```

I know that to change the page, you can use:

```
window.location = "some_url.html";
```

But what I don't know is how to also include the

```
[...] data-ftrans="slide" [...]
```

attribute, like with the HTML hyperlink.

Is anyone able to help with this? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you just set up fasw transitions so that it use "slide" by default? This seems the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First give an ID to `<a id="goToMyUrl" href="some_url.html" data-ftrans="slide">Link</a>`

Then using jQuery

```
$("#goToMyUrl").attr("data-ftrans","slide");
```